# R ggforest(): Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)): names do not match previous names

Tags: r

I just updated R to version 4.2.2 and RStudio to version 2022.12.0+353 and now when I run ggforest() on my Cox model, I get a name match error (shown below).

This is while this exact code was working perfectly prior to the updates. Has anyone else faced such error or know how to fix it?

I'm using a Mac M1, OS version 12.5.1.

```
cx1 <- coxph(Surv(surv_time, surv_status) ~ mygrp + age + sex + educ, data =mydata)
ggforest(cx1, data = mydata)

**Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names**
```

Note that when I run a univariate cox model with any single one of the covariates alone, ggforest() works error-free. But as soon as there is more than one coviariate in the cox model, ggforest() throws the above error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Voting to close for lack of MCVE.

Comment: I would add this as an issue on the github page for the package https://github.com/kassambara/survminer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same issue as you. I solved this by converting my data table from a `tibble` to standard R `data.frame` using the `as.data.frame` function. For example

```
cx1 <- coxph(Surv(surv_time, surv_status) ~ mygrp + age + sex + educ, data = as.data.frame(mydata))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Raramai, I just tried your solution and it worked! I was able to  finally output the forest plot. As the Cox model already worked without applying data.frame() to my data, I think you only need to apply data.frame() to the data within the ggforest() call when passing the data to it. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem this morning. I struggled for an hour and finally solved it. In my case, it goes well when I take the part of `Surv(surv_time, surv_status)` out of the coxph line. Take your case as example, I first set `cx <-Surv(mydata$surv_time, mydata$surv_status)`. Then run  `cx1 <- coxph(cx ~ mygrp + age + sex + educ, data =mydata)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Zhihan. I tried your suggestion and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message when I try to run ggforest() based on the results of cx1. Could you possibly share your version of R and RStudio? and also are you using a Mac M1 as well?

Comment: That is NOT the way that the survival package author expects to have the `Surv` function used. He expects the Surv function to be used in the formula so that the environment for evaluation is clearly maintained.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by that. Which part of the script is against the expected use case of the survival package? Thanks.